# How to map an EF code first V4 to linked server

Tags: entity-framework, linked-server

I want to query an Access database, and since EF does not support Access database, I have created a Linked server to my Access database. The question is: what is the next step ? How I can query the linked server ? how I can update the rows ? how I can map the tables in the linked server to the EF code first classes ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot because EF doesn't support linked servers. What you can try to do is creating updatable database views for linked tables and map those views.

Comment: hi @Ladislav Mrnka, and how I can create updatable database views ?

Comment: Just follow [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx). It should be enough to create single view for every linked table you want to us.

Answer (score 0):

The Linked Server is presumably a SQL Server. You can either use a database first approach using the database on that SQL server to generate your EDMX model, or you can use a code first approach to generate the database, and link to that using Access.

Comment: I succeeded in generating the database from code first, and I changed the mapping (through fluent API) to a synonym that target the access table, but now, I can't update the access database, cause an exception occure:'MSDTC on server XXX is unavailable'

Comment: So now I started the DTC server manually and everything goes ok, but now, I have another error:"The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "AA" does not support the required transaction interface." What is the problem ?